# Add snapshot items to array without looping or forEach

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

Using Firestore, I can assign items to an array with the following:

```
this.Svc.getCategories().valueChanges().subscribe(categories => {
  this.categories = categories;
})
```

However, this listens for changes on the items and would add them to the array on a change.

Using

```
this.Svc.getCategories().get().subscribe(categories => {
  categories.forEach(category => {
    this.categories.push(category.data())
  });
})
```

allows me to add the items to an array without listening for changes.

However, this method required me to either use `forEach` or a loop to push the data into the array.

Is there a way to get a one-time snapshot of the data and assign the data to an array without looping and using `push()`?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Firestore docs for reading data once https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data